# How can I make a vertical tab control in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol

I want to make a vertical tab control with VERTICAL text. Not horizontal text.

Like this:
[image: vertical text]
<sub>(source: [lidorsystems.com](http://www.lidorsystems.com/products/winforms/tabcontrol/features/images/tabcontrol-tabs-on-left.jpg))</sub>

I tried MSDN solution but it makes the text horizontal.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with WinForms (System.Windows.Forms), then set the `Alignment` property of the `TabControl` to `Left`. (You can find it under "Behavior" in the properties window.)

The result looks like this:

[image]